# Adding .jsp code to a .jsp file through servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

Im trying to program a small webshop as a part of a School project. We have to use servlets in java, and therefor .jsp pages too. My problem is that i want to check if the user is logged in. If not, i want to show a login form, if they are logged in, i want to show their shopping basket. The major problem here is, that when i try to send .jsp code to my main .jsp page through my servlet, it dont translate the code, it just simple print out:

Here is my servlet code:

```
package coreservlets;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet({"/loggedIn"})
public class LoggedIn extends HttpServlet
{
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     throws ServletException, IOException
   {
     doPost(request, response);
   }

   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)         throws ServletException, IOException {
 HttpSession session = request.getSession();

 PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

 if (session.getAttribute("loggedInName") == null) 
 {
   pw.println("<tr><td>" + 
     "<%@include file=\"messages.jsp\"%> </td>" + 
     "<td>"
     + "<form action=\"login\" method=\"POST\">"
        + "<table>"
            + "<tr>"
                + "<td>Username</td>"
                + "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" />"
                + "</td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
                + "<td>Password</td>"
                + "<td><input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" />"
                + "</td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
                + "<td></td>"
                + "<td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"login\" /> or" 
                + " <ahref=\"register.jsp\">register here!</a>"
                + "</td>"
            + "</tr>"
        + "</table>"
    + "</form> </td>" +  
     "</tr>");
 }
 else 
 {
     pw.println("<%@include file=\"shoppingBasket.jsp\"%>");

 }
   }
}
```

And in the index.jsp i simple load the servlet above by using:

Is there a smart way to solve this, without it getting to complicated, and without adding a seperate login page (know others done that, but i think that just bring alot of extra trouble to check if people are logged in before checking out and stuff

Please remember this is just a school project, so i know it might not be the smartest way of doing stuff, or the most secure, but its just an imaginary webshop :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way.

JSP will be compiled to plain Java-Servlets who produces HTML in run-time.
You can not use Java to generate JSP who generate Java who produces HTML.

Try to use the

```
package coreservlets;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet({"/loggedIn"})
public class LoggedIn extends HttpServlet
{
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     throws ServletException, IOException
   {
     doPost(request, response);
   }

   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)         throws ServletException, IOException {
 HttpSession session = request.getSession();

 PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

 if (session.getAttribute("loggedInName") == null) 
 {
   pw.println("<tr><td>");
   request.getRequestDispatcher().include("/messages.jsp");  
   pw.println("<td>"
     + "<form action=\"login\" method=\"POST\">"
        + "<table>"
            + "<tr>"
                + "<td>Username</td>"
                + "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" />"
                + "</td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
                + "<td>Password</td>"
                + "<td><input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" />"
                + "</td>"
            + "</tr>"
            + "<tr>"
                + "<td></td>"
                + "<td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"login\" /> or" 
                + " <ahref=\"register.jsp\">register here!</a>"
                + "</td>"
            + "</tr>"
        + "</table>"
    + "</form> </td>" +  
     "</tr>");
 }
 else 
 {
     pw.println("<%@include file=\"shoppingBasket.jsp\"%>");

 }
   }
}
```

instead of the line

```
"<%@include file=\"messages.jsp\"%> </td>" +
```

Regards

Comment: When i tries to use your advise, im getting an error when trying to compile the java file: method getRequestdispatcher in interface ServeletRequest cannot be applied to given types.

Comment: The d is upcase, my bad. It still dont wont compile